grouping column is dropped in later versions of featuretools. Can it be retained?
In former versions of Featuretools, the column that was used to group by and calculate the primitives was retained in the final output. Check out for example the output of this notebook, cell 8, which was done with version featuretools==1.5.0.
Running the code with the latest version does not return the "invoice" column any more. Is there a way to force that column into the final feature_matrix?

Without digging too deep, I'm guessing this might be a typing related behavior change. By default Featuretools only retains categorical, numeric and boolean features in the feature matrix that is generated. What type has been inferred for the "invoice" column by Woodwork? You can check types with es["your_dataframe_name"].ww

Thank you! Indeed, that was it! I set the logical type to categorical and now it worked.
